# How To Add New Line on Metadata by C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, metadata

I have file .XML by Exporting on Gridview But The Metadata showed Like [image]
and i want the metadata like [image]

Here is My Code

```
    private void ExporttoExcel( DataTable table)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename= Att " + txtPeriodeAwal.Text + " to " + txtPeriodeAkhir.Text + ".xml");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<?mso-application progid=\"Excel.Sheet\"?>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(" <Workbook xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\"");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\"");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\"");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("xmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\"");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("xmlns:html=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">");
}
```

Can I get New Line Indent on My metadata base on My Code??

Comment: Side note: constructing XML with string concatenation is bad idea, especially if you don't know how to add new lines... You may want to use more friendly tools like `XDocument`.

Comment: But is there any way to add new line so the metadata change into <br/>?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<br />"); didn't work?

Comment: doesnt work...it just print "<br / >" on metadata...not new line like real <br /> function

Comment: I can fixed now...use ("\n")